# Connecting to MySQL from ExtendScript

Tags: mysql, extendscript

Has anyone successfully connected to MySQL from ExtendScript (Adobe's JavaScript-based application scripting tool)?

ExtendScript's Socket object seems like it could handle integrating the two on a low level. I haven't been able to find a client and I doubt one exists. At this point I'm thinking it'd be easier to create an intermediate script in a language that has great MySQL support and to use sockets to connect to ExtendScript because that would be easier than learning the MySQL protocol and building a client from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [extendables](https://github.com/stdbrouw/Extendables) on github.  It has a package for handling http requests.  So yes, you could use that to connect to a PHP script that interfaces with the MySQL database.  You should realize, though, that sockets in ExtendScript are rather slow, so you might want to go with using ExtendScript's system level calls to the OS shell to handle communication.  Take a look at [my post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619515/cannot-get-access-token-from-oauth-google-api-for-installed-applications) where I was trying to achieve a similar thing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Extendables framework. Thanks also for the tip on making calls to the shell. The database is not on the same machine as Adobe's products but I could easily make a local copy on a local MySQL server. I did also think about seeing if I could port something over from Node but that would have to be a long-term project.